# Python, IIS scripts, and user accounts

Tags: iis, python, user-accounts, wsgi

This isn't a question on my specific problem, as I've got that more or less solved, but about IIS/Python and user accounts in general.

I have python scripts that I'm running with IIS 7.5 (Mercurial using the hgweb.wsgi script). One of the plugins (largefiles) is getting permission trouble reading and writing files.

The script was trying to write files to a temporary directory, by checking the `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variables, which were returning `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local`, and failing due to permissions.

I tried printing the `USERNAME` environment variable, but no matter what user I set in the IIS application pool's Identity, it always returned `MACHINENAME$`

So how can I run python scripts in IIS so that the environment variables point to the correct user's home location? Or is this just a developer error (Hg didn't have the permissions problem, only the largefiles extension)?

In addition, when I originally had the repos in `C:/Data`, the files written by largefiles to that directory have a lock icon and the permissions were `SYSTEM`: full control and `Administrators`: full control, with the owner set to `Administrators` (the group, not the administrator user). After writing the file, it could no longer be read. Even if I gave `Everyone` full control of the `C:/Data` directory, new files would still be locked unless I manually edited the permissions. Again, Hg didn't have this problem, only the files written by largefiles.

Comment: What OS is being used?

Comment: IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Check the UAC event log (Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\UAC\Operational). Do you see events stating "The process failed to handle ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED"?

Comment: Nope, 0 events.

Comment: What is the app pool identity? I think you need to change permissions or the user. See here: http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx

Comment: I've tried setting the app pool identity to both the built-in accounts and custom accounts, in each case the environment variables return `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local` for `APPDATA` and `MACHINENAME$` for the `USERNAME`, and in each case the permission errors still showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to get to the bottom of the permissions issues.

You can use the tool to see what user is trying to access the file as what process and other important details that are handy for troubleshooting IIS permissions.